# VS windows forms

Tags: windows-forms-designer

I was just wondering is there a less bloating and simpler way of clearing input elements say made up of text boxes, check boxes and combo boxes to a empty state, that being removing text from them etc. I have like maybe 50+ and was hoping of a tidier way of doing this.

Another scenario I have is a set of 18+ elements, each set having 2 text boxes and 2 check boxes, one being an 'enabled' check box that when selected will enable/disable its set. Would there be a way of creating a method to handle this and make the required changes rather than having to type out the same thing happening for each set?

```
if (cbEnhancedInputOptionEnabled1.Checked == true)
{
    tbEnhancedInputOptionText1.Enabled = true;
    tbEnhancedInputOptionInputID1.Enabled = true;
    cbEnhancedInputOptionDefaultState1.Enabled = true;
}
else
{
    tbEnhancedInputOptionText1.Enabled = false;
    tbEnhancedInputOptionInputID1.Enabled = false;
    cbEnhancedInputOptionDefaultState1.Enabled = false;
}
```

so I would have 18 of these just changing based on the number which correlates to the set. Each one being in their own cbEnhancedOptionEnabled_CheckedChanged event.

Is there a way of passing controls by reference to a method? that'll do the same as above but to the controls passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first scenario, you can create a method named, for example, ResetAllControls, where you can set the status of each control to its default state.

For the second scenario, you may implement CheckedChanged event for each checkbox to control what to be enabled/disabled.

Another option is to give prefixed name for each control in each set. For example, set1_txtBox, set2_ddl, etc. Then define a common method. The method should accept a parameter (based on the prefix or set order number) to decide which set that you want to enable/disable. In that method, you can loop through the list of controls of the Form and, based on the parameter, and enable/disable which controls that you wish. Finally, you can implement the CheckedChanged event for each checkbox that is responsible for enabling/disabling each set's status. In each CheckedChanged method, you call the common method and pass your parameter.

Let me know if these help you.

Comment: Your first two ideas is how I currently have it but to give better context, for the first scenario I have a method that auto fills the controls to a hard coded state, one that loads in the previously entered stuff, and one to clear them all, which is like 200+ lines total to do very similar things I was hoping to reduce the amount of lines but I am unsure if that's actually possible through some techniques I possibly don't know.

Comment: Well it could be, if it falls into one of the following cases.

1) Your data (for the controls) came from a centralised data source (csv, xlsx or a database) that can be grouped based on some data similarity rules.

2) Your controls can be grouped based on their names and functionalities. In that case, you may consider my 3rd option above and customise it for the scenario.

Comment: Normally I don't ask people to post their code, as I respect their freedom and their privacy. But in this case, to assist me to provide you the best solution possible, it'd be great if you can post your sample so I can take a look.

Comment: huh just creating a method to take them and then simply passing them seems to work never mind :P

Comment: That's great. Good for you.